# Comparing definitions of vector fields

Tags: differential-geometry, definition, differential-topology, differential-forms, tensors

Let $M$ be a manifold and $X$ a vector field on $M$.

There are three ways how one can think of this vector field:

**As a (smooth) section of the tangent bundle**:
$X_s: M \rightarrow TM$

**As a derivation**:
$X_d: \mathcal{C}^{\infty}(M) \rightarrow \mathcal{C}^{\infty}(M)$

**As a $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(M)$-linear map**:
$X_l: \Omega^1(M) \rightarrow \mathcal{C}^{\infty}(M)$

---

Identifying the tangent space at a point $p \in M$ as the vector space of derivations at that point, i.e. $T_pM \simeq \{ \partial_p :\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(M) \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \, | \, \partial_p \text{ derivation}\}$, I am aware of the following identification:
$$X_s(p)(f) = X_d(f)(p) \in \mathbb{R} \, , $$
for $p \in M$ and $f \in \mathcal{C}^{\infty}(M)$.

Now my question is, how does the identification of $X_l$ fit into this picture? More precisely:

> Given, $p,q \in M$, $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(M)$ and $\omega \in \Omega^1(M)$ such that
>   $$X_l(\omega)(q) = X_d(f)(p)\, ,$$
>   holds. How are $p,f,\omega$ and $q$ related?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, for the exterior derivative $\omega = df$ we have
$$X(\omega) = \omega(X) = df(X) = X(f).$$
So, the answer is $\omega= df$ and $p=q$.

Comment: Interestingly, this shows that you cannot recover directly from $X_d$ the action of $X_l$ on arbitrary $1$-forms, only on locally exact (i.e., closed) ones. You have to use linearity over $C^\infty$ to get complete information.

Comment: So you mean that every one-form $\omega$ can (locally) be written as $\omega = g \cdot df$ with $f,g \in \mathcal{C}^{\infty}$? In particular, if that is true, can I not simply find a function $h \in \mathcal{C}^{\infty}$ such that $dh = g \cdot df$?

Comment: No, every $1$-form can be written as a linear combination of such expressions. Moreover, you certainly can't (locally) write $g\,df = dh$ unless $d(g\,df) = 0$. This was the point of my original comment.

Comment: Ah, I think I get it now! Thanks for that, I gained some insights.